# Why are the sequence of SSH.exec commands not continuous?

Tags: ruby, unix, ssh, sudo

What I want to do is:

- login as root
- `su postgres`
- `psql jumlar < database_schema.txt`

This is my code. As you see I have to do those step by step, I can't do these two steps in one command:

```
Net::SSH.start(192.168.2.1, root, :password => "root") do |ssh|
  ssh.exec! "su postgres"
  ssh.exec! "psql jumlar < database_schema.txt"
```

However, this is not going to work after `su postgres`, as the second `ssh.exec` doesn't do thing after the first one. It seems that it always opens a new tunnel.

I do not know if Ruby has a command that remembers every step or not?

Comment: Why not do it in one string though? `ssh.exec! "su postgres; psql jumlar < database_schema.txt"`

Comment: The commands can be continuous to a point. Look into the `su` and `sudo` docs more, especially the `args` parameter to `su` and `command` for `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `su` command opens a new shell. The second command doesn't run until the first commands finishes, but the first command won't "finish" until you exit and terminate the new shell (and then you won't be in the context of the postgres user anymore).

One solution would be to run the desired command as postgres using:

```
  ssh.exec! "sudo -u postgres 'psql jumlar < database_schema.txt'"
```

See the [sudo command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for more information.